# Create directory through C# using WinSCP on SFTP server

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

We are writing a console application in C# to upload files, through WinSCP .NET assembly using SFTP protocol, to the file server. I am able to connect to the server and place files to the server but not at the exact place I want. Please find the code as below:

where

```
path = \Repository\Scan\Java\ant\UAT
zippath = C:\Temp\UAT_17-11-2016-19_40_05.zip
sftppath = \Repository\Scan\Java\ant\UAT\UAT_17-11-2016-19_40_05.zip
```

ZIP file is getting placed at `Repository` folder level with name as `RepositoryScanJavaantUATUAT_17-11-2016-19_40_05.zip`. If the directories don't exist on the server they are not getting created.

```cs
using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);
    {
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
        }
        else
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            Console.WriteLine(
                "The directory was created successfully at {0}.",
                System.IO.Directory.GetCreationTime(path));
        }

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Put Files in the folder");
            TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;
            TransferOperationResult transferResult;
            transferResult = session.PutFiles(zippath, sftppath, false, transferOptions);
            transferResult.Check();
        }                
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- You cannot use the `System.IO.Directory.Exists` to check an existence of SFTP directory, nor you can use the `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory` to create a directory on the SFTP server. Use the WinSCP [`Session.FileExists`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_fileexists) and [`Session.CreateDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_createdirectory) methods:

  ```
  if (session.FileExists(path))
  {
      Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
  }
  else
  {
      session.CreateDirectory(path);
      Console.WriteLine("The directory was created successfully");
  }
  ```
- SFTP paths use a slash, not a backslash:

  ```
  path = /Repository/Scan/Java/ant/UAT
  sftppath = /Repository/Scan/Java/ant/UAT/UAT_17-11-2016-19_40_05.zip
  ```